# Hive External table does not showing in Namenode (Cloudera-QuickstartVm)

Tags: bigdata

I have created external table in Hive in the hdfs path 'hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/training'. If I apply describe command I can find the table path as shown below. But when I browse through the namenode web page, the table name does not showing up in the path.

```
hive> describe extended testtable4;
OK
firstname   string  
lastname    string  
address string  
city    string  
state   string  
country string  

    ***Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:testtable4, dbName:default, owner:cloudera, createTime:1408765301, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:firstname, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:lastname, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:address, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:city, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:state, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:country, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/hive/training, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=,, field.delim=,, line.delim=    
    }), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{EXTERNAL=TRUE, transient_lastDdlTime=1408765301}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE)       
    Time taken: 0.7 seconds***
```

Comment: This isn't a great fit for the Data Science site. I'd suggest posting this in serverfault.com perhaps.